# ClientBundle and Images GWT Exception

Tags: java, gwt, resources, clientbundle

I am trying to use ClientBundle in GWT To load messages.

Here is my code:
gwt.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module rename-to='StockWatcher'>
    <!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff.                        -->
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>

    <!-- We need the JUnit module in the main module,               -->
    <!-- otherwise eclipse complains (Google plugin bug?)           -->
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.junit.JUnit'/>

    <!-- Inherit the default GWT style sheet.  You can change       -->
    <!-- the theme of your GWT application by uncommenting          -->
    <!-- any one of the following lines.                            -->
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard'/>
    <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.chrome.Chrome'/> -->
    <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.dark.Dark'/>     -->

    <!-- Other module inherits                                      -->

    <!-- Specify the app entry point class.                         -->
    <entry-point class='ro.gebs.master.client.StockWatcher'/>

    <!-- Specify the paths for translatable code                    -->
    <source path='client'/>
    <source path='shared'/>
    <source path='resources'/>

</module>
```

The interface that extends ClientBundle:

```
public interface Resources extends ClientBundle {
    Resources IMPL = (Resources) GWT.create(Resources.class);

    @Source("ro/gebs/master/resources/blogger.png")
    ImageResource blogger();
    @Source("ro/gebs/master/resources/delicious.png")
    ImageResource delicious();
    @Source("ro/gebs/master/resources/facebook.png")
    ImageResource facebook();
}
```

Here i try to use the images in my EntryPoint class:

```
ImageResource[] icons = new ImageResource[]{
                Resources.IMPL.blogger(),
                Resources.IMPL.delicious(),
                Resources.IMPL.facebook()
        };
```

And the error i get:

```
Exception while loading module ro.gebs.master.client.StockWatcher. See Development Mode for details.

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:411)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:200)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:526)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at ro.gebs.master.client.StockWatcher.onModuleLoad(StockWatcher.java:24)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Deferred binding failed for 'ro.gebs.master.client.Resources' (did you forget to inherit a required module?)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:53)
    at com.google.gwt.core.shared.GWT.create(GWT.java:72)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.create(GWT.java:86)
    at ro.gebs.master.client.Resources.<clinit>(Resources.java:12)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.rebind(ModuleSpace.java:610)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.rebindAndCreate(ModuleSpace.java:470)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:49)
    ... 13 more
```

The images are placed in a package named 'resources' but what i understand form the error is that the line with `GWT.create()` seems to be the problem.

Comment: where is the `resources` folder in your project?

Comment: at the same level with client, server and shared packages, but that does not seem to be the problem, the problem comes at line GWT.create(), my code doesn't even get to that.

Comment: Make sure images are placed there.

Comment: Images are placed there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try relative position as shown below

```
@Source("../resources/blogger.png")
ImageResource blogger();
@Source("../resources/delicious.png")
ImageResource delicious();
@Source("../resources/facebook.png")
ImageResource facebook();
```

---

Project structure

```
ro/gebs/master
            |
            |__resources
            |          |
            |          |__blogger.png
            |
            |__client
                     |
                     |__StockWatcher.java
```

---

--EDIT--

**Make sure that images are placed under correct location with correct name and extension.**

Comment: No, it's the same case

Comment: Working fine for me. There is no need to add `<source path='resources'/>` in this case.

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Deferred binding failed for 'ro.gebs.master.client.Resources' (did you forget to inherit a required module?)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:53)
 at com.google.gwt.core.shared.GWT.create(GWT.java:72)
 at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.create(GWT.java:86)
 at ro.gebs.master.client.Resources.<clinit>(Resources.java:12)
 ... 10 more`

Comment: I am still getting this, i replaced with relative position. Resources cannot be instantiated from what i understand...

Comment: you were right, the code works fine, i had an image with the .jpg extension and not .png... sorry for the stupid question and thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Resources` path entry in {module}.gwt.xml. it does not require.

```
<source path='resources'/>
```